# Marten - using sequences - add new sequence fails on 2nd run

Tags: c#, postgresql, event-sourcing, marten

I tried to add a new "custom" sequence to my Marten DB to get a user ID for new users (during registration).

```
builder.Services.AddMarten(o =>
{
    o.Connection(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MartenPg"));
    if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        o.AutoCreateSchemaObjects = AutoCreate.All;

    o.Storage.ExtendedSchemaObjects.Add(new Sequence("userId_seq"));
}).ApplyAllDatabaseChangesOnStartup().UseLightweightSessions();
```

Later I was able to access the next sequence value as:

```
var userId = session.Query<Int64>("select nextval('userId_seq')").First();
```

The problem is in the upper code: for the 1st run it works: adds the `userId_seq` to the database. But on the 2nd start it tries to add again - but the sequence already exists so it fails. Tried to find a way to determine if the sequence is already added or not - but cannot find any - the `ExtendedSchemaObjects` is always empty. Otherwise - I think it is not my fault as the method name `ApplyAllDatabaseChangesOnStartup` suggests me it should be determined by the the built-in migration tool.

Any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a lower-case sequence name (and make your life easy by always only using lower-case names in PG)

---

A bit of background: if you don't double quote an identifier in PG, it is automatically converted to a lowercase. Similarly, when querying the sequence (or any other object), it is converted to its lowercase form unless it is double quoted.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE TEST;
SELECT NEXTVAL('test'); --OK
SELECT NEXTVAL('teST'); --OK
SELECT NEXTVAL('"test"'); --OK, lower-case name is found
SELECT NEXTVAL('"TEST"'); --ERROR, nothing found.

CREATE SEQUENCE "TEST2";
SELECT NEXTVAL('test2');  --ERROR, nothing found.
SELECT NEXTVAL('"TEST2"'); --OK, double quoted name with upper case is found
```

Back to marten/weasel:

[Code](https://github.com/JasperFx/weasel/blob/6b22dd7ea122c75605ad2d0e894781bf31698614/src/Weasel.Postgresql/Sequence.cs#L40C13-L40C13) to create the sequence does not add double quotes, so your identifier is converted to lower case.
When you query the `nextval`, the identifier is also not double-quoted so its lower case version is used and the sequence returns the desired value.

Next time you run your app, the [code](https://github.com/JasperFx/weasel/blob/6b22dd7ea122c75605ad2d0e894781bf31698614/src/Weasel.Postgresql/Sequence.cs#L58C10-L58C10) that looks if the sequence exists or not uses the identifier as-is, so containing an upper-case. There is no sequence under that name so the sequence is created again, using again the lower-cased name, which already exists.

Comment: Ahh I see. As I used other SQL servers - it is not obvious for me that PG likes (only) lower-cased names... but your advice works! Thanks!

Comment: I wonder as the `Sequence` class is part of the Marten lib - is there any chance to gives us a warning, or do this trick behind the scene?

Comment: @ZoltanHernyak see how the reported [issue](https://github.com/JasperFx/weasel/issues/100) gets resolved